# Visual Studio - blank line at the end of each new file

Tags: visual-studio, editor, settings, eof, blank-line

Why does VS add a blank line at the end of each new file I create? I use VS to create .NET projects (not C++ or something).

Is there any special reason? Historical compatibility with compilers and parsers?

Can I disable this??

Comment: Some compilers / tools in the past have had difficulty with files where the last line doesn't end in a carriage return.  But you're unlikely to be able to find the *actual* answer...

Comment: Please always add a newline at the end of file - please

Comment: On Linux, if you `cat` a file from the terminal, and it doesn't end in a line break, your next terminal prompt will appear at the end of the last line of the file, rather than on it's own new line. Not sure about the corresponding Windows `type` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is recommended to have a blank line at the end of each file for navigability purposes. Think what happens if someone opens your code with vim for example and uses a keymap to jump from empty line to empty line. Or, if he decides to add another portion of code at the end of file he can quickly do a GO and enter it instead of having to scroll until the end of file.

Also, source control tools will report more changes if you don't have a trailing blank line when you try to insert code at the end of file.

Comment: So what happens if someone opens my code with vim? BTW, what's the m in vim?

Comment: I know, I was trying to hint that it's called improved but it's not improved enough ;)

Comment: Vim deals just fine with files without blank lines at the end, it doesn't break `G` navigation at all. Jumping from blank line to blank line (I'm assuming you mean using `{`/`}`) also deals fine with this. The source control reason also seems kind of silly, especially considering that in C# for example you never insert code right at the end, as it's always in a namespace/class block anyway.

Comment: A text editor shows you a new line. But technically there isn't one. The newline char is part of the last line not the new line. So it's good to have all lines end with a `CR LF` / `LF`

Comment: The real reason is probably in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/1178235
It's not about recommendation, but about POSIX compliance (which is not cosmetic, but guarantees you interoperability).

Comment: @Strigoides well, now as of C#9 you can write top-level programs in where you totally are going to add code to the end of the file :)

Comment: Also, source control tools will report more changes if you don't have a trailing blank line when you try to insert code at the end of file.

=> Can you make an example?

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to get rid of the new line at the end of a file:

I had a similar issue and the solution provided by [9paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8058099/9paradox) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758898/how-can-i-disable-auto-new-line-in-visual-studio-code/72916115#72916115) solved my problem.

When I was saving my code (Python, JSON, JS, etc...) I got always a new line inserted at the end of the file.

Solution: if, e.g. on Mac, you are editing any file in your project, then go to the root directory of your project, let's say `/Users/<username>/git/<project>` then search for `.editorconfig` in that folder, then open that file with any text editor like `vi` or `TextEdit` and make `insert_final_newline = false`. `VS Code` takes over the settings changes immediately. No restart needed.