# Visual Studio Code - New blank line at the end of file when saving

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ecmascript-6, insert, newline

(There's a similar question asked >> [Visual Studio - blank line at the end of each new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690951/visual-studio-blank-line-at-the-end-of-each-new-file). But This is the complete opposite. And that doesn't answer this)

I have Visual Studio Code Version 1.19.0 on OSX. 
JavaScript (ES6) linter wants me to add a new blank line at the end of each file. When I hit save after adding a new blank line myself at the end of the file, VS Code removes that automatically. My concern is that, overriding any DEFAULT User Setting won't fix that.

Anyone with a solution? Thanks in advance.

(Setting I tried overriding but failed >> "files.insertFinalNewline": true)

Comment: Are you sure it's VSC doing that and not another separate configuration (I'm thinking `.editorconfig`)?

Comment: nope. All clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the linter rule that enforces you to enter new line at the end 
so this will work

if you use ESlint you cab use the rul **eol-last** and set its value to "never"

in your .eslintrc file

```
{
"rules": {
   "eol-last" :"never"
   }
 }
```

learn more
[eol-last ESlint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eol-last)

Comment: I guess that is the one which did the trick. Thanks a lot. What a pain that was. In love with VSCode again. he hee..

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to get rid of the new line at the end of a file:

I had a similar issue and the solution provided by [9paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8058099/9paradox) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758898/how-can-i-disable-auto-new-line-in-visual-studio-code/72916115#72916115) solved my problem.

When I was saving my code (Python, JSON, JS, etc...) I got always a new line inserted at the end of the file.

Solution: if, e.g. on Mac, you are editing any file in your project, then go to the root directory of your project, let's say `/Users/<username>/git/<project>` then search for `.editorconfig` in that folder, then open that file with any text editor like `vi` or `TextEdit` and make `insert_final_newline = false`. `VS Code` takes over the settings changes immediately. No restart needed.