# How can I disable auto new-line in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, visual-studio-code

The problem is after I've installed the Angular extension in Visual Studio Code, I constantly get across all files (.ts, .html, and .css) auto new-line after typing single letters or multiple lines of code. It's frustrating. I disabled prettier, word-wrap, and intellisense, but the problem still remains.

Is there a way I can disable it?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you type and when/where it adds the newline?

Comment: is the typed line is the last line in VS code?

Comment: I type 'e' it goes new line...i type 'export' it goes new line...it's doing it in every file type. 'Insert New Line At the End Of File' is disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Visual Studio Code — Insert New Line at the End of Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704968/visual-studio-code-insert-new-line-at-the-end-of-files)*

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.

After going through my extensions, I noticed that the "**[EditorConfig for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig)**" extension I installed was inserting auto new-line after typing single or multiple lines of code.

If the problem is still not solved, try disabling some extensions and see if that works.

Comment: Making insert_final_newline = false in .editorconfig file should fix the behavior of automatic inserting of new line after typing single or multiple lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and the solution provided by [9paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8058099/9paradox) solved my problem.

When I was saving my code (Python, JSON, JS, etc...) I got always a new line inserted at the end of the file.

Solution: if, e.g. on Mac, you are editing any file in your project, then go to the root directory of your project, let's say `/Users/<username>/git/<project>` then search for `.editorconfig` in that folder, then open that file with any text editor like `vi` or `TextEdit` and make `insert_final_newline = false`. `VS Code` takes over the settings changes immediately. No restart needed.

Comment: You are awesome man. Thanks a trillion. After lots of failed tries I got this awesome solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem / frustration, particularly with Angular .html (.css lines don't get that lengthy anyway, and my team is tight with the .ts formatting standards).

Search vscode settings for `HTML > Format: Wrap Attributes` and `HTML > Format: Wrap Line Length` and play with the options.

In the end I had to revert since other team members were using the system defaults, git was going to show way too many changes. But if you're working on your own thing then this works. Don't forget you can also change the settings just for a particular workspace.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Quit wrapping to fit into the width of a straw.  Who has 800x600 anyway these days.  I don't like magic without a way to control it.  Lol

Answer (score -8):

Just disable the auto save option in VSC.

Comment: *How* is that achieved? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68210989/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: what if you *need* the auto save option?..