# Visual Studio Code keeps creating new line

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

In every file in Visual Studio code is causing a new line at the end, this happens when the file is saved (autosaved) or formatted

[image]

Is there a way to turn this feature off, so it doesn't keep creating the final new line..

I've already tried

```
"files.insertFinalNewline": false,
"files.trimFinalNewlines": false,
```

Neither of these work, any ideas how to turn this off?

Comment: Does whatever project your are working on have an .editorconfig file or something similar?

Comment: omg how embarrassing.. yeah that was it, wont believe how long ive been trying to resolve this lol

Comment: Hehe! Consider closing this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758898/how-can-i-disable-auto-new-line-in-visual-studio-code